# Trying to paint on a QLabel fails (cannot call member function 'virtual void QLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)' without object)

Tags: c++, qt, paint

I have seen many examples on how to use a paintevent, but I just cannot get it to work.

I have in my .ui file a label named 'image' and I am trying to paint inside it. I fail miserably. In most of the examples I've seen they use the

```
QLabel::paintEvent(e)
```

but I cannot use this, I get:

```
error: cannot call member function 'virtual void QLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)' without object
```

And, when I use

```
ui->image->paintEvent(e);
```

I get

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qlabel.h:141: error: 'virtual void QLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)' is protected
```

I seem to be missing something... That's the part of my code that I try to implement this:

```
void crop_my_image::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    ui->image->paintEvent(e);
    QPainter painter(ui->image);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(0,0,0,180)),1,Qt::DashLine));
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,120)));
    painter.drawRect(selectionRect);
}
```

`crop_my_image` is of QDialog type!

PS: If, instead of `ui->image->paintEvent(e);` I use `QDialog::paintEvent(e);` I can successfully draw on my dialog, so I should be in the right path!

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do exactly the same with label what you did with QDialog, which is create class which will inherit from QLabel and implement paintEvent function. Example:

```
//MyLabel.h
class MyLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        MyLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    private:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

//MyLabel.cpp

MyLabel::MyLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent)
{
    /*...*/

}

void MyLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    /* paint somehting on your label*/
}
```

And than you will be able to do:

```
void crop_my_image::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{
    myLabelObject->paintEvent(e);
    QPainter painter(ui->image);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(0,0,0,180)),1,Qt::DashLine));
    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,120)));
    painter.drawRect(selectionRect);
}
```

But firstly, why event you want to invoke this method?

Comment: hm... I still don't seem to get it... Is it somewhere obvious that MyLabelObject and ui->image is the same thing? (if the question seems dump to you, what documentation do you recommend reading?)

Comment: No, it's not the same. In 'default' QLabel, paintEvent is virtual and protected. To use it you have to reimplement it in your own class. Secondly, it even doesn't make sense to invoke method, on which you don't have any control but you would like to, does it? Next, you still didn't answer my question - what you want to achive by invoking paintEvent for QLabel? Maybe you just picked wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: I am just trying to implement this: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/12207 (Kxyu's suggestion)

Comment: Okey, now i know what's going on. He have you great answer and he gave you almost the same example as i did, so i don't know where is the problem? He created class which inherits from QLabel and reimplemented paintEvent function, just as i did. AS i see you didn't do this, but u created only class which inherits from QDialog (you forgot about QLabel). That's all.

Comment: So, tell me if I've understood correctly. I need to make a new class ( let's say `MyImage` ) that inherits from QLabel, and declare there all the functions, like `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);, void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);, void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);, void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e);` and then call from inside there the `QLabel::paintEvent(e)`. But this way I am not able to access through the MyImage class the ui->image label (on which I want to draw). I mean, I cannot call `QPainter painter(ui->image);`

Comment: You don't have to reimplement all functions, just these you need (which actually is only paintEvent). Also you don't have to call QLabel::paintEvent(e), just draw what you want. If you would call this function, it would draw whole picture, which as i understod, you don't want to. And at last, you won't have to get to ui->image label, because all you will do in your own label (MyLabel class). That's why u have to create it, to now draw whole picture with using default QLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) method.

Comment: Got it. I will make an MyImage Object, add it to my layout and then anything else (there shouldn't exist anything in my .ui file). Right?

Comment: I will just wait to solve it myself (doing something else currently)

Comment: So why u asked for helped on forum if you wanted to solve problem yourself?

Comment: your answer doesn't solve my question. First I try, and, if I succeed, I come here and vote as solved. Logical.

Comment: Wait a second. Why have you wrote that my answer didn't solve the problem and then you wrote that you will try it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15412/discussion-between-user9379-and-blood)