# How to draw a point on top of a QImage for Qt5

Tags: qt, qt5

I am fairly new to Qt and I am completely stuck at this point. My only option was to turn to the experts. I have designed a GUI that will load an image into a Qlabel on a QMainWindow. I then want to draw multiple points on the image itself. However, what seems to be happening is that the point is being drawn behind the image and I don't know how to draw the point on top of the image.

My Code:

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();

   return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMouseEvent>

//Declaring the external Variables
extern QString name;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();

private slots:

void on_actionOpen_triggered();
void on_actionDraw_2_triggered();
void on_actionCreate_2_triggered();
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e);

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "createdialog.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <qpainter.h>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QLabel>
#include <Qimage>
#include <QPaintDevice>
#include <QDebug>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/path.hpp>
#include <boost/system/config.hpp>
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

QString fileName;
QString name;
int drawFlag=0;
int paintFlag=0;
int xCord = 0;      //mouse click x location
int yCord = 0;      //mouse click y loaction

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
  QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
  delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
//Opening a dialog box to search for the images
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setNameFilter(tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));
dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"),
                                                   "C:/", tr("Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg)"));

//Pulling just the file name out of the file path
    std::string filename = fileName.toStdString();
    boost::filesystem::path p(filename);
    name = QString::fromStdString(p.stem().string());

//Checking to see if the file name is empty
if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
    QImage img(fileName);
    int width = img.width();
    int height = img.height();
    MainWindow::showMaximized();
    ui->label->setGeometry(0,0,width,height);       //Setting the label to the size of the image
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));  //Inserting the image into the label

}
    else{
       ui->label->setText("Error");
}

}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
 {
  //If the draw flag is set record mouse press events
  if(drawFlag==1){
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton){
        xCord = event->x();
        yCord = event->y();
        std::cout << "x-location: " << xCord << endl;
        std::cout << "y-location: " << yCord << endl;
        paintFlag=1;
        update();

    }
  }
}
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* e)
{
  QMainWindow::paintEvent(e);
  //When the paint flag is set then paint
  if(paintFlag==1){
    QPainter painter(this);
    QPen paintpen(Qt::red);
    paintpen.setWidth(10);
    QPoint p1;
    p1.setX(xCord);
    p1.setY(yCord);
    painter.setPen(paintpen);
    painter.drawPoint(p1);
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_actionDraw_2_triggered()
{
drawFlag=1;

}
```

Any advice is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main window is drawn before its child widgets are drawn. Drawing the main window is actually just drawing the gray background.

That means your `MainWindow::paintEvent()` calls the base class implementation (`QMainWindow::paintEvent()`) to draw the gray background, and then draws a point on top of the gray background. After the ``paintEvent()` returns, Qt draws all child widget, including the label, on top of that, thus drawing over the gray background and over your point.

Potential solutions:

1. Before calling `QLabel::setPixmap()`, draw the point **on the QImage** - `QPainter` can draw on `QImage` as well, not just on `QWidget`.

---

```
QImage image("path/to/image/img.png");
QPainter painter(&image);
QPen pen;
pen.setWidth(20);
pen.setColor(Qt::red);
painter.setPen(pen);
painter.drawPoint(5,5);
painter.end();
label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
```

---

2. Subclass `QLabel` (name it e.g. LabelWithPointOnTop) and override `paintEvent()` in your subclass, then put an instance of your subclass instead of `QLabel` into your layout.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am still a little confused on the implementation. I'm not to sure how I would draw the point on the QImage before calling Qlabel::setPixmap()

Comment: Would it be possible to give an example of potential solution 2 as well. I understand your example code for 1 but when implementing it, it still isn't working. Thank you!

Comment: This is an example on how to subclass QLabel (see first answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973691/trying-to-paint-on-a-qlabel-fails-cannot-call-member-function-virtual-void-qla

However, you also need to integrate the QLabel subclass into your UI file, which is an entirely different topic.

Comment: Okay. I'm kinda understanding subclasses but is possible to subclass a QLabel for a QMainWindow. I am doing all of this in the QMainWindow because I have different tab options at the top of my UI and one of the them is draw so that I can draw onto the image, which is on the Main Window.

Comment: @pdm The example should work. You set the pen width and color for the painter before drawing the point, right?

Comment: Yeah I set the width and color and I tried to add that code in the void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_triggered() before I called ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img)); but It didn't work.

Comment: @pdm I modified the example code, and I tested it and it works.

Comment: I finally got it to draw on the image all thanks to @thuga. Thank you very much.